# Comma and dot on decimal keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

I have a decimal keyboard and I want to have on it dot and comma . Is it possible by default?

I was trying to add a custom button, but the method addDot it's not called . Any idea why or how can I do this?

```
 -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
     if ([self.cowPrice isFirstResponder] ) {
         UIButton *commaButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
         [commaButton setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 206, 53, 55)];
         [commaButton setTitle:@"," forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [commaButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addComma) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         [commaButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
         [ self.cowPrice.inputAccessoryView addSubview:commaButton];
         [self.cowPrice.inputAccessoryView bringSubviewToFront:commaButton];
     }
 }

-(void)addComma{
    NSLog(@"yes");
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you please upload screenshot? how you screen look like? if you do not have any issue.

Comment: it seems like that you are not able to click  on UIButton..

Comment: I added also a screenshot.

Comment: Please check your device region, as per my knowledge dot or comma its depend upon region. if it german then show comma and if it is US then its show dot.

Comment: yes , i know this , but i want to display both

Comment: Why do you need both? Just add the extra one to the `inputAccessoryView`.